# Use spring-data-jpa and dozer in spring-mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, dozer

In `spring-data-jpa`, the repository returns `Page<T>`, implementation classes is `PageImpl<T>`, then I can't use dozer to convert it, because the `pageImpl` has two methods: `hasContent()` and `getContent()`, dozer can't the analyze type.
`PageRequest` missing no parameter constructor, dozer can't convert too. My solution is to rewrite them, do you have a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an extra class and map your page to it, here an example:

Spring configuration for Dozer : (exmaple : xml files are under **src/main/resources/META-INF/dozer** )

XML config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">


 <mapping wildcard="true" type="one-way">
    <class-a>com.comp.proj.domain.SrcClass
    </class-a>
    <class-b>com.comp.proj.model.DesClass
    </class-b>
</mapping>



<mapping wildcard="false" type="one-way">
    <class-a>org.springframework.data.domain.Page</class-a>
    <class-b>com.comp.proj.model.PageResponse
    </class-b>
    <field>
        <a>totalElements</a>
        <b>totalElements</b>
    </field>
    <field>
        <a>totalPages</a>
        <b>totalPages</b>
    </field>
    <field>
        <a>content</a>
        <b>desClasses</b>
    </field>
</mapping>



</mappings>
```

Spring configuration :

```
<bean class="org.dozer.spring.DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean">
            <property name="mappingFiles" value="classpath:META-INF/dozer/*.xml" />
   </bean>
```

Page Responce Class:

```
public class PageResponse {


    private List<DesClass> desClasses;

    private Integer totalPages;

    private Integer totalElements;

    //sertters and getters
}
```

Now in your controller just inject : `Mapper`

```
@Resource
Mapper mapper;
```

and Convert Your `Page<SrcClass> page` to `PageResponse` this way :

```
mapper.map(page,PageResponse.class);
```